# Unreal 4.24.3 : Create Loading screen

Tags: unreal-engine4

What I want to do-
Create a loading screen when I spawn multiple actors(1000ish) after the level is loaded.

What I have attempted so far: (Inside of BeginPlay() of an actor)

```
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("%s: Begin - %s"), *FString(__FUNCTION__), *FString(FDateTime::Now().ToString()));

    FLoadingScreenAttributes attribs;
    attribs.WidgetLoadingScreen = SNew(SRPGLoadingScreen);
    attribs.MinimumLoadingScreenDisplayTime = 3.f;
    attribs.PlaybackType = MT_Normal;
    attribs.bAutoCompleteWhenLoadingCompletes = false;

    GetMoviePlayer()->SetupLoadingScreen(attribs);

    FPlatformProcess::Sleep(5.0f); //placeholder for spawning 1000 actors

    GetMoviePlayer()->StopMovie();

    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("%s: End - %s"), *FString(__FUNCTION__), *FString(FDateTime::Now().ToString()));
```

I am new to Unreal and would appreciate any pointers to what I am doing wrong and how to go about this.

Comment: I have also tried FNonAbandonable task but you can't spawn actors from any other thread than main-thread

Comment: All of the methods mentioned here are for loading level, not use above use-case:=> https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/vr-ar-development/71264-several-methods-for-making-loading-screen-would-like-some-suggestions-and-idea-sharings